# how to define a keyspace dynamically in accessor

Tags: java, cassandra, mapping, accessor

I am attempting to create an accessor to run slightly more complex queries in cassandra with java. I have no problem with the syntax, and I can get it to work, but my question is this: is there a way to dynamically declare a keyspace in an accessor? 
For example, if you create a table map for the MappingManager you would declare the @Table and give it the keyspace and table name like so:

```
@Table(keypace="mykeyspace", name="orders")
public class Orders {
    @PartitionKey
    public UUID id;
    //blah blah blah, rest of code
}
```

Now creating an accessor for that specific table is easy enough:

```
@Accessor
public interface OrdersAccessor {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE status = :status")
    Result pending(@Param("status") Integer status);
}
```

Simple. The problem is it demands a keyspace, and I am a huge fan of never hard-coding anything. I realize that I am "hard-coding" the keyspace in the Table definition in the MappingManager class definition, but if need be I only change it there and it updates everything that has to do with that. If I hard-code the keyspace in every single @Query definition inside the Accessor I will have to change, potentially, a bunch of different items if the keyspace gets updated, instead of only changing it one place in the @Table definition.
I have been searching Google for hours and I can't find a single instance of someone dynamically declaring a keyspace with an accessor, only thousands of examples of accessors where they are hard-coding the keyspace into the @Query like so:

```
@Accessor
public interface OrdersAccessor {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM keyspace.orders WHERE status = :status")
    Result pending(@Param("status") Integer status);
}
```

I realize the query I wrote isn't really cause for an accessor, I was just simplifying it for the sake of the example. So I am coming to the community asking for help, I can't find any examples of this anywhere. I can't imagine that I am the first person to ever want to do this, I just can't find any examples of anyone else tackling this problem. Thank you in advance for any help you can give, I can really use it.

Comment: may be you can define keyspace and tables in properties or constants file

Comment: @undefined_variable I thought about doing that. The other thing I was thinking of trying to solve is... My company has a lot of different "keyspaces" one for each client, and some of the applications I program need to be able to connect to all keyspaces. In php it was simple to make a dynamic switching device, but with Java it is much harder, since you have to define the keyspace in the declaration with "@Table". Do you know of any way to have the same Java class be used across keyspaces?

Comment: were you able to figure it out? I am working on solving the same problem.

Comment: @Sudhir yes I was. Instead of defining the keyspaces in the files themselves I created a "parent" database object that had a connection to each keyspace, then just added the fiel to that map. Something like...
Session crSession = cluster.connect("mykeyspace");
Session otherSession = cluster.connect("otherkeyspace");
dbMap.put("crSession", crSession);
dbMap.put("otherSession", otherSession);
then add the maps to it
MappingManager crManager = new MappingManager(crSession);
MappingManager otherManager = new MappingManager(otherSession);
Then you can add your maps to that, and boom.

Comment: @Sudhir If you want I will post up my full code here for you to see as an example. It was a tricky solution, but it works perfectly.

Comment: Considered that approach. But was worried about the impact on the server. A session is fairly heavyweight per this old answer https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/d/msg/java-driver-user/p6edKPkFNBE/aI6M_ciIW3IJ . Your code would be helpful. An alternate approach I am considering is implementing the methods with an additional keyspace parameter.

Comment: @Sudhir With the approach that I took, it only connects to a keyspace if the request is made for that keyspace. It creates everything needed to do it, but doesn't connect to a keyspace until you tell it to get the connection for that keyspace. That way it doesn't just have a bunch of open connections to every keyspace when it isn't needed. I will post up an example of what I have in a few minutes, I'll just use this thread.

Answer (score 1):

@Sudhir Here is the solution I came up with. I am sure there are better ways to handle the connections, but I am still pretty new to cassandra and Java, and this is working well for my needs. I hope this helps...

```
public class DbInterface {

private Cluster cluster;
private Session session;
private Map<String, Session> dbMap;
private Map<String, Map<String, Mapper<Class>>> mappers = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public DbInterface(String host) {
    Map<String, Session> connections = createConnection(host);
    Session crSession = connections.get("crSession");
    Session hppSession = connections.get("hppSession");
    cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(host).build();
    Session crSession = cluster.connect("mykeyspace");
    Session hppSession = cluster.connect("hpp");
    MappingManager crManager = new MappingManager(crSession);
    MappingManager hppManager = new MappingManager(hppSession);
    mappers.put("mykeyspace", new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
    mappers.put("mykeyspace2", new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
    Map cr = mappers.get("mykeyspace");
    Map hpp = mappers.get("mykeyspace2");
    cr.put("status", crManager.mapper(OrderStatus.class));
    hpp.put("status", hppManager.mapper(OrderStatus.class));
    cr.put("status_accessor", crManager.createAccessor(OrderStatusAccessor.class));
    hpp.put("status_accessor", hppManager.createAccessor(OrderStatusAccessor.class));
    cr.put("users", crManager.mapper(Users.class));
    hpp.put("users", hppManager.mapper(Users.class));
    cr.put("orders", crManager.mapper(Orders.class));
    hpp.put("orders", hppManager.mapper(Orders.class));
    cr.put("order_detail", crManager.mapper(OrderDetail.class));
    hpp.put("order_detail", hppManager.mapper(OrderDetail.class));
    cr.put("chal_orders", crManager.mapper(ChalOrder.class));
    hpp.put("chal_orders", hppManager.mapper(ChalOrder.class));
    cr.put("chal_order_detail", crManager.mapper(ChalOrderDetail.class));
    hpp.put("chal_order_detail", hppManager.mapper(ChalOrderDetail.class));
    cr.put("detail_accessor", crManager.createAccessor(OrderDetailAccessor.class));
    hpp.put("detail_accessor", hppManager.createAccessor(OrderDetailAccessor.class));
    cr.put("tracking_labels", crManager.mapper(TrackingLabels.class));
    hpp.put("tracking_labels", hppManager.mapper(TrackingLabels.class));

}

public Session getConnection(String type) {
    if(dbMap.containsKey(type)) {
        return dbMap.get(type);
    }
    if(dbMap.containsKey(type.toLowerCase() +"Session")) {
        return dbMap.get(type.toLowerCase() +"Session");
    }
    return dbMap.get("crSession");
}

public Map<String, Session> createConnection(String host) {
    dbMap = new HashMap<>();
    cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(host).build();
    Session crSession = cluster.connect("mykeyspace");
    Session hppSession = cluster.connect("hpp");
    dbMap.put("crSession", crSession);
    dbMap.put("hppSession", hppSession);
    return dbMap;
}

public Map getDBMap(String client) {
    if(mappers.containsKey(client)) {
        return mappers.get(client);
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Unknown Client: " + client);
}
```

}

One of the things I was thinking of doing is moving the session creation and Map creation to separate functions, then only connect and build the map for the session that is needed. Like instead of defaulting to connecting to both sessions when the DbInterface() is called, only connect to the session that is requested via the "host" param.

Anywho, I hope this helps you out. If you need it, here is an example of my other library that uses this...

```
public class MyRestController {

    private final DbInterface db = new DbInterface(IPADDRESS);

    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping("/status")
    public String getStatus() {
        Map managerMap = db.getDBMap("mykeyspace");
        OrderStatusAccessor statuses = (OrderStatusAccessor) managerMap.get("status_accessor");
        Result<OrderStatus> allStatuses = statuses.getAll();
        //rest of the code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Neglected Sanity, even i have the same requirement, can you please let me know the solution ?